# Make gconftool-2 set wallpaper from root dir

Tags: permissions

There are wallpapers in a root directory.
I need to set to some user that I choose a wallpaper from that directory.

How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: For now, you can't do that with gconf because of a bug that will get fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:

```
#Make wallpaper directory in an appropriate location
mkdir /var/wallpaper  
#Set RW permission for all  
chmod 666 /var/wallpaper  
#Set sticky so all new files catch that permission  
chmod +t /var/wallpaper  
#copy your wallpapers there  
cp ./wallpapers* /var/wallpaper/
```

then **select wallpaper from /var/wallpaper/ in gconftool-2**

that should do it...